# Не удается сделать push

Tags: git

Не получается залить изменения в созданный на сервере репозиторий.

Создал, как описано в первом пункте [тут](http://proft.me/2011/01/15/svoj-udalennyj-git-repozitorij-pod-ubuntu-centos/).

Добавил удаленный репозиторий для локального.
При push выдает ошибку

> fatal: '/var/www/rusa/data/www/abrus1987.fvds.ru/email/foo.git' does
>   not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Comment: перевод последней строки: пожалуйста, убедитесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа и что репозиторий существует.

Comment: Нет прав на запись, говорит.

Comment: я на сервере сижу под root

Comment: права на папки 755

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы делали. по приведённой вами ссылке нет ни первого пункта, ни упоминания каталога `/var/www/rusa/data/www/abrus1987.fvds.ru/email/foo.git`.

Comment: Создание удаленного git-репозитория, управляемого доступом по ssh - это первый пункт. Делал по нему. Естественно нет каталога, потому что это мой каталог, а в статье приводится каталог автора статьи

Comment: Люди, вопрос открытый. Может не хватает прав на var стоит 755

Comment: @ruslik, попробуйте 777 поставить, _5_ - чтение и выполнение, если не ошибаюсь - запись не входит

Comment: Это не опасно, у меня в этой папки еще другие сайты и ставить 777 на var как то не очень мне кажется

Comment: @ruslik, можно права 777 поставить на папку репозитория, а не на всю var

Comment: В таком случае это не решение, тк на папку foo.git стоят права 777

Comment: @ruslik а можете добавить в вопрос, какой командой вы пушите? В смысле все параметры, а не только, что это git push.

Comment: @ruslik помнится, когда я настраивал git репозиторий, там даже из за прав на каталоги и владельцев, могли вознникать ошибки, почитайте об этом поподробнее, я точно не помню, как верно сделать, так же посмотрите что там в gitosis, почитайте  поподробнее о конфигах. Ведь он управляет пользователями, в ообще все жто есть в gitbook

Answer (score 6):

Так как входных данных мало, то ответ будет больше похож на алгоритм решения подобных проблем.

Далее `сервер` – это машина, где расположен удаленный репозиторий, в моем случае Linux (Ubuntu), `клиент` –  машина на которой клонируется репозиторий, в моем случае Mac OS.

**1)** Смотрите под кем работаете на сервере (полезно иногда смотреть кстати)

```
who
```

**2)** Какая версия гита

```
git --version
```

**3)** Смотрите права на сервере, где расположен удаленный репозиторий

```
 cd /var/www/rusa/data/www/abrus1987.fvds.ru/email/foo.git
 ls -alF
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Права должны быть и на чтение и на запись

**4)** Смотрите под каким юзером и по какому урлу вы подключаетесь к удаленному репозиторию, на клиенте

```
git config --list | grep "remote"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если юзеры из `п. 2)` и `п. 3)` не совпадают, значит надо менять. Нужно что бы на сервере для директории с удаленным репозиторием были права на чтение и запись хотя бы для группы, в которой находиться юзер из `п. 3)`.

Если пушите под разными юзерами, то возможно поможет восстановление прав на запись для группы.

```
chmod -R g+w .
```

Что бы вам помочь, дайте больше информации:

1) Под кем работаете на сервере (`п. 1)`)

2) Какая версия гита (`п. 2)`)

3) Какие права стоят на удаленном репозитории на сервере (полный вывод из `п. 3)`)

4) Какой конфиг в локальном репозитории на клиенте (полный вывод из `п. 4)`)

5) Если доступ у клиента к серверу по `ssh`